# git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey) from public repository

Tags: git

I can not clone repositories from github even if there are public:

```
git clone https://github.com/github/fetch.git
Cloning into 'fetch'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Everything works if I want to clone from e.g. bitbucket.

Comment: You wrote clone command with `https://` URL but Git started to clone with `git@` scp-like SSH URL. This means you have [`url.….insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) in your Git configs. Run `git config --list --show-origin | grep -Fi insteadof` and comment out or remove configurations that you do not need now.

Comment: @phd - it's already an answer IMHO, not just comment

Comment: @LazyBadger Well, for an answer it should be expanded. Done, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You wrote clone command with `https://` URL but Git started to clone with `git@` scp-like SSH URL. This means you have [`url.….insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) section(s) in your Git configs that overwrite your URLs on the fly.

Run

```
git config --list --show-origin | grep -Fi insteadof
```

to find out where exactly is the problematic configuration and comment out or remove what you do not need now.

Most probably you have a section like this in your global `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

To remove it:

```
git config --global --remove-section url.git@github.com:
```

Or use your editor to inspect and edit the file:

```
git config --global --edit
```